# Experience Manager Best practice for Default SiteEdit tags

Tags: experience-manager

What is the best practice to render following site-edit tag using Enable Inline editing for page TBB on .aspx pages.

Since i have master page not managed inside Tridion, all page templates render output within Content Place Holders only.

But after adding "Enable inline editing for Page" below DWT page TBB, it renders the below siteedit tags after last content placeholder.

How can i manage these output within any placeholder?

```
<!-- Page Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:193-48251-64","PageModified":"2014-12-22T10:21:06","PageTemplateID":"tcm:193-48260-128","PageTemplateModified":"2015-02-26T09:03:57"} -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" defer="defer" src="http://tridionwebsite/WebUI/Editors/Siteedit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js" id="tridion.siteedit"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the online documentation ([docs.sdl.com](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-CDBFB30A-AE02-4379-8C53-AFCF32B80FFD)) there is a topic about how to get the bootstrap script rendered in a location of your liking.

When you add the **Enable inline editing for Page** TTB on a Page, you can control the location of the bootstrap script by placing the following HTML comment in your Page:

```
<!--SITE_EDIT_INIT-->
```

So when you have this comment in the appropriate content place holder, then you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks Bart, this was same feature we used in siteedit, somehow i overlooked and got confused. thanks for your help